# Is it impossible to put SwiftUI view into a framework?

Tags: swiftui

In terms of modularization, it makes sense to separate the different parts of an application by creating and using frameworks.

So I tried to create a framework that shall encapsulate a set of SwiftUI views for a specific purpose. However, it seems that this does not work in terms of buildability and previewability.

Is it known if there are any restrictions on how SwiftUI can be used within a framework?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Putting a SwiftUI view into a framework seemed an obvious thing to do, but when I try, it gives the error: **NoBuildableEntriesError: active scheme does not build this file**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting the following error as well?

> NoBuildableEntriesError: active scheme does not build this file

It does indeed appear that previews won't work when the view file's within a framework, which is crazy; however, it is possible to include views *after* building them. I managed to make it work by:

- Building the view within an App project, so I could use previews, etc.
- When completed, moving it from the App to the Framework.

The resulting app will still build & run. I appreciate this is a ridiculous workaround, but at least it does mean that the views can be re-used without duplication.

Very much hoping Apple will address this soon!